# ComponentDidmount loads once in lifetime. I wanted to load it every time whenever i visit previous screen

Tags: react-native

ComponentDidmount loads once in a lifetime. If I open a tab then it will be called but if I switch to another tab and then go to the first tab componentdidmount will not call again. I need some method which will call even when tab has been rendered earlier and I visit other tab then come back to first tab and it again runs.

Comment: you should checkout the `useFocusEffect` hook

Answer (score 0):

Use this focus listener.

```
 componentDidMount() {
    this._unsubscribe = this.props.navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      // do something
    });
  }
```

Comment: it does not work properly.... you will write "willFocus" or "didFocus" instead of "focus"... then it works.... but the problem is still same .... actually the main problem is ... when i login to account .. i want to change my profile icon... it changes correctly first time (fist time is page load correctly)... but when i go to logout page to logout user... and redirect to home page ... it does not change my profile icon(means it does not refresh page second time)... what i can do now ? ... if you did  not uderstand, tell me... i'll explain it further

Answer (score 0):

you should add Focus listener in your project like that :

```
  componentDidMount() {
        
        const { navigation } = this.props;
        this.focusListener = navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => {


            console.log("refresh shod");


        });
    }
```

and this for remove listener :

```
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.focusListener.remove();

      }
```

Comment: it works only first time..... But actually the main problem is ... when i login to account .. i want to change my profile icon... it changes correctly first time (fist time is page load correctly)... but when i go to logout page to logout user (clear cache)... and redirect to home page ... it does not change my profile icon(means it does not refresh page second time)... what i can do now ? ... if you did  not uderstand, tell me... i'll explain it further

Comment: can you add code of project for check your problem

Comment: componentDidMount() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    navigation.addListener('didFocus', () =>
      this.getToken()
    );
  }

                                                                                                                              
   async getToken(user) {
    try {
      let userData = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userData");
      let data = JSON.parse(userData);
      if (data !== null) {
        this.setState({ Login: true })
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Something went wrong", error);
    }
  }

Comment: on top code .... there are 2 functions... [compoenentDidMount() and async getToken()]..... it works first time .. first time when i visit back to home page where i written that code ... it true login state and change the icon button....... but after login, when i go to logout page (when user logout , it redirect to home also) ... it does not work (it clear cache) but it does not false the login state.... that's why icon does not change ....

Comment: async componentDidMount() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    try {
      let userData = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userData");
      let data = JSON.parse(userData);
      if (data !== null) {
        navigation.addListener('willFocus', () =>
          this.setState({ Login: true }),
          console.log('Mount')
        );

      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Something went wrong", error);
    }
  }

Comment: for more help please edit your question and add code there